# Logging into CP doesn't set authentication cookie

Tags: control-panel, cookies, authentication

Trying to debug an issue where in a dev environment logging into the cp it doesn't set the CP Authentication Cookie (the hash with the _identity) at the end of it. I believe this is the root cause of why no entries load and any request to the craft api returns a 400 with a response of Forbidden: Login Required.

This is the weird part because I am able to log in initially but after doing so it is as if i'm not logged in and I can only see a few things.

The other thing that happens is after a minute the session expired modal will pop up and after entering my pw again the modal won't go away. Now if I check my cookies I'll see the authentication cookie but it seems to automatically expire after it get set.

[image: Response when app tries to get elements]

[image: Cookies after it prompts me to re login]

Comment: I'd probably make sure your PHP sessions are properly working first... Craft's identity cookie is based on a working PHP session, so if that's failing it might describe the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I do believe I see a cookie being set named PHPSESSID with a long string as the value so i'm going to be guessing it's working but I can double check.